# ZF2 shared installation for many virtual hosts

Tags: zend-framework2, centos

I have many projects in the same Centos server and I'd rather like to install ZF2 once in a location like /usr/share/zf2 instead installing it with Skeleton all the time as duplicate libraries with projects and use ZF2_PATH in all my applications. Naturally, I'd like to use composer to update this shared zf2 library as well.

I can make it work in my way but I'd like to know if there is a conventional/preferred way to do this.

What I would do is:
1- Install ZF2 in /usr/share/zf2
2- Set ZF2_PATH environment
3- Remove Zend Framework 2 requirement from composer.json of the projects and update all as necessary.

I am just trying to follow a proven/accepted/easy-to-maintain method instead discovering it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are all your projects going to require the same version of ZF2? It seems unnecessary to couple them all together like this when composer makes dependency management so easy. The whole framework is 3.2 megabytes (zipped), if this is a space saving solution, you're probably doing your applications more harm than good.

Comment: I agree. I was actually more concerning about updating ZF library as I have many applications in the same servers but then I was convinced it is absolutely unnecessary and as you nicely pointed out - "more harm than good". Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unconventional, there is no "proven/accepted" way of doing it and many people will have different opinions.

Downside of your solution is the need of testing all 3 apps when upgrading Zend Framework, I am sure you can imagine multiple scenarios when it could be handy to upgrade it just for one. If anything goes wrong, and things do go wrong, you will end-up breaking all 3 apps, not just one.

The only upside is saving space, but is that really an upside any more? Isn't disk space very cheap. Breaking your code is definitely more expensive (I am talking about cost of your time, potential loss of data or users).

If you still want to proceed you can create a 4th project with its own composer.json file and use it for any shared dependencies.

Comment: I absolutely agree as I found out yesterday after making a few hours research.  I was about to delete my question then but I didn't, because I couldn't have found a good "why shouldn't I do that" answer so I decided to keep it as future reference for possible others. Thank you for exactly clear answer.